# Qt grabbing activity under android

Tags: android, qt

Device or OS, firmware: Android

Hello all!
Who in the subject prompt, such a problem:
there is an application for android written in Qt in it, I use the class `QuickGstInput` which grabs the picture from the "main activity", the problem is that if the application is minimized, or go to the slip (by the power button for example), then the picture stops grabbing (the corresponding function is not called)
actually the main question: can I even grab an active image in a background / slip (it's about my application)?

Made by:
I tried to force the grabbing function, I get something like this: `QOpenGLFramebufferObject :: toImage ()` called without a current context
such a suspicion that video card is generally cut off in such regimes, is it ?...